# Compilation error with template and lambda with Clang

Tags: c++, c++14, clang++

I was trying to compile a project with a code that looks like this

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

struct Foo
{
};

template <typename... Args>
void start(Args&&... args) {
    auto x = [args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)] () mutable {
            auto y = [args] () mutable {
                auto z = [] (Args&&... args) {
                    return new Foo(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
                };
            };
    };
}

int main()
{
    start(Foo{});
}
```

It seems to compile fine in GCC 4.9.1 but not in Clang 3.4, 3.5, 3.6. The error message is

> error: variable 'args' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with
>   no capture-default specified

Is it a compiler bug? If so, is there any workaround to get it to compile on Clang?

Comment: This would be a lot easier to test if it were an [MCVE](http://stackoverf.low.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @chris I tried [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91e2026261ba5375) in a recent clang++ and got an ICE :(

Comment: Well, [3.7.0 r236860](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Kwxv5czipmd42sKm) seems to handle it fine. Note I turned off warnings as a dirty way to remove the unused variable clutter.

Comment: Reduced to http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdc0b6ab9b36bf15. Per @chris, looks like a since-fixed Clang bug.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17853

Comment: @T.C., Looks like the answer to me :) At least it would go great with a workaround. I'm pretty sure changing the outer lambda to contain an `auto &&x = a;` line and then capturing `x` would work.

Comment: @chris Or just use another init-capture - `[a = a]` rather than `[a]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reduced to:

```
template <typename T>
void start(T t) {
    [a = t] { [a]{}; };
}

int main()
{
    start(0);
}
```

Which [generates the same error in non-trunk versions of clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdc0b6ab9b36bf15).

This appears to be caused by [a bug in Clang's handling of a non-init-capture of an init-capture](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17853). Said bug was fixed yesterday, May 7, and the current trunk version of Clang compiles the code above correctly.

Since this bug only manifests for non-init-captures of init-captures, a simple workaround is to use an init-capture in the inner lambda as well - instead of `[a]`, do `[a = a]`.

Comment: I'm curious: How did you find that bug report?

Comment: @dyp I searched all Clang bugs for "capture init-capture". It's the first item in the list.

Comment: I tried to search earlier with the exact error message but I didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: @Nat It's pretty hard to find unless you know what to look for :)